# PayPal UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT

Tags: android, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

we are using **PayPalAndroidSDK.jar** in Android to do the payment transaction directly from app. We already created a business account successfully and the app is working fine in sandbox.

But when we are changing it from **Sandbox to Live** and tried to do the payment using original LIVE US credit card, it's giving us below error:

```
request failure with http statusCode:401,exception:org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Unauthorized
request failed with server response:{"name":"UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT","message":"Unauthorized payment.","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors","debug_id":"d658b"}
```

**We used below code to do the payment:**

```
PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration()
            .environment(PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION)
            .clientId(CONFIG_CLIENT_ID)
            .rememberUser(false);
```

[We are using this client id in the app.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Rs32.png)
[This is the latest settings which we have in the account under app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZF6PI.png)

It would be great if someone could help us in this.

Comment: what API did you call?

Comment: We are not calling any API as we are using PayPalAndroidSDK.jar directly and calling PayPalService class directly and rest of the thing will be handled by PayPal itself.

Comment: using PayPal SDK means that you are calling an API to complete a transaction. in this case, I bet you are calling Direct payment which your account are not authorized for.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a new integration?

"Unauthorized payment" could be that you dont have the permission to run Direct Credit Card payment REST API.

REST DCC will be available only to existing merchants and new merchants in Japan. The. You may option to use Website Payments Pro/ Payflow Pro to use Direct Credit Card Payment

Comment: We are using PayPalAndroidSDK.jar to do the transaction from app directly. Also, we gave the required permission as shown in the screenshots in my question. Do we must have to set required details in Payments Pro to get it working ?

Comment: You will need to use diferent kind of integration. You can refer here for a list of SDK:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/nvpsoap-sdks/